# Whats the interface in angle brackets in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin I often read

```
class MyFragment : BaseMvpFragment<MvpView, MvpPresenter>(), MvpView {}
```

whereas `MvpView` and `MvpPresenter` are interfaces.. so `MyFragment` extends `BaseMvpFragment<MvpView, MvpPresenter>()` but how can I interpret `<MvpView, MvpPresenter>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `BaseMvpFragment` obviously defines two generic types which are being specified via `<MvpView, MvpPresenter>`.

Consider the `List<T>` interface. When you implement it, it looks like this:

```
class VerySpecialList : List<String> { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

They are type parameters; see [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html).